# Help promote this site - ask your Thanksgiving / large group cooking questions here

Tags: discussion

Now that much of the world is entering a big holiday season where food is central to celebrations, people will have lots of cooking questions. We've already missed Canadian Thanksgiving and India's Diwali, but American Thanksgiving is coming up, as well as other harvest-type festivals. Since these issues will apply to this season every year, it's a great opportunity for Seasoned Advice to build up a canon of holiday / large group cooking questions that can be referenced for years to come. This will be a great way to attract new members as well - people who are hosting Thanksgiving for the first time, looking to make substitutions to traditional dishes for health reasons, or who are trying out new recipes for the sake of being adventurous and branching out from traditional menus.

What can you do to help?

As you prepare for Thanksgiving or any other holiday approaching in the next few weeks, ask questions here whenever you have them. No matter how silly they may seem, you're probably not the only one having that question! Ask them even if you think you're going to be able to find the answer yourself... and if you do find the answer, go ahead and answer it yourself.

When answering holiday cooking questions or questions about cooking for large groups, do everything you can to overkill it. Don't just answer with a hyperlink to some other discussion group somewhere. Write a detailed, step-by-step, ultra-clear guide with photos and examples. Help us have the best possible answer to the common problems and questions people have with holiday cooking.

If a question comes in that is unclear, badly written, badly formatted, or in bad English, edit it into shape. We've always encouraged edits that improve spelling, grammar, and clarity. Make every question into a full sentence.

This is a great opportunity to build up a body of answers to common Thanksgiving and other seasonal holiday questions that will be super-popular in the coming weeks as people plan and execute holiday menus. Those questions will bring in lots of traffic from search engines and if Seasoned Advice continues to have great answers like we have in the past, we stand a chance of attracting some great new users who will add value for years to come.

*Note: Shamelessly stolen and adapted from [Joel's successful promotion](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/q/589/10998) to build new content for Apple SE.*

Comment: Don't forget to use [the appropriate tag](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/thanksgiving).